# Socket Programming- reading message from open ports

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to read the message from all the open ports on my system. But i am not getting any output. Following is the code:

```
public class ReadPort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int port = 0; port <= 65535; ++port) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port), 1);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String text = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message from Port #" + port + " : " + text);
                socket.close();
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.remainingMillis(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at ReadPort.main(ReadPort.java:6)
```

Comment: You can't connect to port zero. I formatted this mess for you.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to connect all port from `0 to 65535` that doesn't mean you can connect will all port. Not all port is listening connection for connection listening must need TCP or UDP server.

You can find information about port and which server using which port in general case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers. So basically in your machine available port may be `10 to 100`(may be or not).

So now you can connect with those `10 to 100` socket server. But after connection, it's not sure that server or another party will send something. In most case, commnunication happen `request(client) and response(server)` based. Here you are a client so That's why you are not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have some serious misunderstandings about how sockets work.

1. Most ports on your system will reject connection requests.  Only ports that are bound to a running server process will accept connections.
2. After you make a connection successfully, you usually SEND data to make a request from the server, i.e. an HTTP `GET` request.  Many servers wait until you send something before responding. Attempting to read from a connected socket without sending anything first will just time out, as you already saw, although some servers, like SMTP, send a banner message which you *could* read.
3. If you want to do something meaningful, you have to know what server process you are connected to, and what protocol it understands, in order to know what to send.  This is why there are ["standard" ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) such as 80 for HTTP and 22 for SSH.

I strongly suggest you go through the [Java Tutorial on Networking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/TOC.html)